# How to filter out files with certain file extensions in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For example, I have 1000 files under a repo, I want to filter out all files with `.vue`/`.tsx` extensions, not searching for their content, rather just filter by the file names, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, just found out I could do that by using `Ctrl`+`P` (go to file), and type `.vue`/`.tsx` to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? [vscode file navigation](https://www.kimsereylam.com/js/2020/05/22/vscode-file-navigation-tips.html). You can use search settings to filter files.